# event onactivityresult doesn't work

Tags: android, events, onactivityresult

I'm beginner on Android development so I have a question for experts

My event onActivityResult doesn't work and I don't understand why..

This is my principal activity which launch the sub-activity

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, ...) 
{
    Object o  = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String str = (String)o;
    Dog d = new Dog();
    d.setName("Blacko");
    d.setKind(str);
    d.setAge(2);
    d.setColor("Noir");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DogDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("Dog", d);
    startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_OK);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, ...) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if( requestCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        String name = data.getExtras().getString("DogName");
    la.add(name);
    lv.setAdapter(la);
    }
}

And here, this is the code of my sub-activity

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{  
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("DogName", Name.getText());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

I have already searched on many forums for solutions (Android: launchmode in manifest, setResult to 0 ,etc..) and posts here concerned this problem..
But I didn't find solution..

Answer (score 0):

You should not use RESULT_OK in your startActivityForResult because RESULT_OK is a constant which value is -1 and if the requestCode is lower than 0, it won't be passed in onActivityResult();

Define your own constant (`PUBLIC STATIC FINAL int DOG_REQUEST = 1;`) and use it in both `startActivityForResult(intent, DOG_REQUEST);` and `onActivityResult(...)`, `if(requestCode == DOG_REQUEST)`

See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) about this.

Answer (score 0):

go through onActivityForResult:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int)